First ssh-agent request fails on WSL with systemd socket-activation
Running Fedora on WSL2, I find that the socket activation on ssh-agent doesn't quite work properly: the first request that triggers the actual service starting fails. This may be a git fetch or git pull request, or else an ssh-add call. This shows up as a long timeout on the client call rather than as an immediate failure.
Because the systemd config contains both ssh-agent.socket and ssh-agent.service, attempting to disable ssh-agent.socket and enable ssh-agent.service directly doesn't work, as it just turns the socket activation back on rather than configuring the service to start automatically:
~$ systemctl --user is-enabled ssh-agent.socket
enabled
~$ systemctl --user is-enabled ssh-agent.service
indirect
~$ systemctl --user enable ssh-agent.service
~$ systemctl --user is-enabled ssh-agent.service
indirect
~$ systemctl --user disable ssh-agent.socket
Removed "/home/acoghlan/.config/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/ssh-agent.socket".
~$ systemctl --user enable ssh-agent.service
Created symlink /home/acoghlan/.config/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/ssh-agent.socket → /usr/lib/systemd/user/ssh-agent.socket.


Rather than adjusting the systemd config (which is not only likely to end up being distro-specific and may change over time, but would also affect cases where I wasn't starting an interactive shell), I wanted something I could add to my .bash_profile that would ensure that the actual ssh-agent service was always running for interactive sessions, not just a listening socket.
ssh-add -l (listing loaded key fingerprints) seemed like a good trigger command (since it would remind me to run ssh-add if I was planning to use SSH), with timeout used to detect failures (since ssh-add -l should normally be near-instant if the agent is working properly).
This gives the following workaround (I added this to the end of .bash_profile in my home directory):
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/ssh-agent.socket"

timeout 1 ssh-add -l # Ensure ssh-agent service is actually running
if [ $? -gt 1 ]; then
    echo "Attempt to contact ssh-agent failed, retrying..."
    sleep 1 # Give socket activation time to sort itself out
    timeout 1 ssh-add -l  # Keep timeout in case agent really is down
fi

(ssh-add -l reports an exit code of 1 if no keys are loaded, but 2 if the connection attempt fails. Since the timeout failure codes are all 124 or higher, checking [ $? -gt 1 ] detects any failure when attempting to activate the socket. Checking only for the timeout error codes frequently still fails immediately after an instance restart with the message "Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory")
Example output from a new terminal session following a WSL2 instance restart:
Error connecting to agent: No such file or directory
Attempt to contact ssh-agent failed, retrying...
The agent has no identities.
~$ _


OpenSSH ssh-agent does not support socket activation – it doesn't know that it has to receive socket handover from parent, and always establishes its own socket instead.
So your first request gets stuck in limbo inside the queue of the systemd-established socket (which ssh-agent has just unlinked and replaced with its own), whereas the second request now goes through a different socket which just happens to have the same name.
This is not a timing issue; socket activation is "instant" by its nature (when used with programs that know how to accept it), specifically because the initial request stays in the socket queue for as long as the program needs to initialize before picking it up – which is actually what leads to this problem when the program doesn't know how to accept it. (So it's kind of the complete opposite of "needing time to sort itself out".)

I actually suspect there are two layers to the race condition: the way it behaves in practice suggests that the WSL2 runtimes (at least the Fedora Remix for WSL) are set up to allow terminal connections while systemd is still bringing up parts of the system (hence the domain socket sometimes being missing entirely)

If it's missing entirely, yes. But the "long timeout" you've described is very explicitly not a race condition.

Yeah, originally I only checked for timeouts, and that seemed to be enough in manual testing. The non-existent socket handling came from actually trying it in my profile after instance restarts.

For non-socket-activated services, assuming WSL handles the user service manager like normal distros, linking a service into basic.target (instead of default.target) should make it start during the login and not sometime later.
